# Store downloded media like whatsapp in android

Tags: java, android

In android API 29 and higher i have a problem to store data in internal storage
I used code below but user have not access to the files with file manager to delete them.
How can i save data like whatsapp in in internal storage> android>media>package ...

```html
    String path="";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
      path = cont.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
      path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "";
    }
```

[whatsapp data storing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4RXy.jpg)

Comment: Also on Q+ you can store your files in that public directory.

Comment: @blackapps when i store mp3 files on internal using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectoryT next time i haven't access to read that on some devices

Comment: Which devices? And how dit you store?

Comment: @blackapps samsung a31, i stored using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

Comment: If your app can write a file in a directory than it can certainly read that file. Hard to believe it can't.